# How can my addon import SCSS from bower and export CSS for host apps?

Tags: ember.js, sass

I'm using [Ember CLI Sass](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass) within my addon (named `nmbl-foundation`), and I want this addon to customize & include Foundation and auto-import it for host apps.

I followed the [Addon usage](https://github.com/aexmachina/ember-cli-sass#addon-usage) section of the docs but I'm having a hard time getting the importPaths to be correct.

I tried customizing the `appConfig` from `my-addon/config/environment.js`. If I make it

```
module.exports = function(environment, appConfig) {

  return {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: ['node_modules/nmbl-foundation/bower_components/foundation-sites/scss']
    }
  };

};
```

then everything works for external host apps, but the addon's dummy app breaks. I can make it work for the dummy app by changing the above to

```
module.exports = function(environment, appConfig) {

  return {
    sassOptions: {
      includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation-sites/scss']
    }
  };

};
```

but then this breaks for the host app - that is, unless the host app also `bower install --save foundation`.

Is it possible to get a setting to work for both cases, and potentially even situations where this addon is a second-order dependency? Ideally I want my addon to include its local Bower copy of Foundation so the host app doesn't need to worry about installing it (or any other deps this addon my bring in in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use with bower dependency:

Create a default blueprint for your addon. In its `afterInstall` hook, you can add bower packages to the application's `bower.json`. No need to worry about `bower install --save foundation`.

Here is a reference document for [blueprint hooks](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#blueprint-hooks). You can have a look at afterInstall and beforeInstall hooks.

Here is a sample code from [ember-bootstrap](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/blueprints/ember-bootstrap/index.js).

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't need the parent to have the bower dep listed in its own bower.json, but it turns out this is still required.

Comment: Well, my guess, there must be a way to do this as your hope.

Comment: @SamSelikoff did you ever figure out a better way of doing this?

Comment: @aandis I'd probably open a new question or ask in Discord since this question is over 4 years old :)